# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns "C:\\Windows\\system32"

Tags: maui-blazor

I think is an issue

Create a new project Maui Blazor Net 8.0

In a button execute Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }
}
```

is there a possible fix?, i am using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() to try to get to the wwwroot folder where i have a folder with images that i want to transform to 64Base

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the physical path of wwwroot, in a Blazor app razor page without a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183250/how-can-i-find-the-physical-path-of-wwwroot-in-a-blazor-app-razor-page-without)

Comment: Does it help [Dotnet Maui Blazor App - How to access images in wwwroot from static classin android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455046/dotnet-maui-blazor-app-how-to-access-images-in-wwwroot-from-static-classin-and)?